# Apple plant abnormal leaves

Tags: leaves, pest-damage, apples

I have a apple plant which is about 5months old(guessed). As you can see in the image below the new leaves are curling up. I don't know what causes this or how to treat for this. This has happened to other plants than apple plants in my garden. How do I treat this?

Soil: potting soil with cow dung mixed.

Country:Sri Lanka

Plant gets full sun for the whole day.

Watering is done about every 2days.

Max temp 35C

Lowest temp 25C

(I know that it may not be possible to grow apples where I live. But I want to give it a try.)

[image: apple plant]

Edit : more images. 
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: It's could some sort of piercing/sucking insect.  Have you checked the underside of the leaves to see if there are any signs there?  Perhaps you can post a picture of the underside of the leaf also.

Comment: @Ben I updated the main post with more images.

Comment: Could this be sunburn?

Comment: thanks for the updated photos.  I can't tell exactly, but the first of the photos that you added shows what looks like a grain of rice on the leaf, that's probably some type of aphid.  I can't see them on the rest of the photos, but I'm guessing there are more.  In newly added photo 4 I can see some leaf damage the looks like it might be from some sort of leaf minor (but I'm not as familiar with those).  Sunburn would be across the entire leaf, usually yellow turning to brown with age.  Only the part(s) of the leaf exposed to the sun would be burned.

Comment: Partial shade? Doesn't look much like sun damage, but at those temperatures it might be getting dry too often.

Comment: I think the creature on the bottom of the leaf is a leafhopper nymph. The damage on the lower leaves may be due to leafhoppers, but it's definitely from a pest. (Possibly spider mites, though, but they're not my primary guess.) I'm not sure about the upper leaves.